# How to get the result of resultset in a arraylist?

Tags: java, jdbc, collections

I have a method - `read()` - and I want store `resultSet` in an `ArrayList`. I also have a getter/setter class according to my column name. How can I store `resultSet` in an `ArrayList`?

```
public T read(T t) {
    if(t instanceof AddressData) {
        try
        {
            if(dbConnect.getConnectionStatus())
            {
                connection = dbConnect.openConnection();

            }
            else
            {
                throw new InstantiationException();
            }


             preparedStatement = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM AddressData");
             resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
             while(resultSet.next())
             {
                   ((AddressData) t).setAddressId("addressId");
                   ((AddressData) t).setAddressLine1("addressLine1");
                   ((AddressData) t).setAddressLine2("addressLine2");
                   ((AddressData) t).setCity("city");
                   ((AddressData) t).setState("state");
                   ((AddressData) t).setCountry("country");
                   ((AddressData) t).setPinCode("pinCode");


             }


        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you getting an error with this code? Is `resultSet` defined as a member variable or something?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7690/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-convert-a-java-resultset-to-an-object

Comment: my sir gave me this link but i cant understand how to implement it in my program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the current method signature you probably can't. The issue is that you return only one instance of `T` and not a `List<T>`. Worse still, you fill data on the variable `t` given as parameters.

Assuming I understand your need, the following code should be a good beginning (assuming all strings).

```
public List<T> read (T t) {

    List<AddressData> addresses = new ArrayList<AddressData>();

    if (t instanceof AddressData) {
        try {
            if (dbConnect.getConnectionStatus()) {
                connection = dbConnect.openConnection();

            } else {
                throw new InstantiationException();
            }

            preparedStatement = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM AddressData");
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                AddressData a = new AddressData();
                a.setAddressId("addressId"));
                a.setAddressLine1(resultSet.getString("addressLine1"));
                a.setAddressLine2(resultSet.getString("addressLine2"));
                a.setCity(resultSet.getString("city"));
                a.setState(resultSet.getString("state"));
                a.setCountry(resultSet.getString("country"));
                a.setPinCode(resultSet.getString("pinCode"));

                addresses.add(a);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return addresses;

    } else {
        // ...?
    }

}
```

Note that one new `AddressData` instance is created per iteration on the `ResultSet` and is added to the `List<AddressData>` that is returned from the method. You should reconsider what to do in case `t` is not an instance of `AddressData`, but this is out of scope of your question.

Comment: i have setter/getter class that have method public void  setAddressData(String AddressData) {
  AddressData = AddressData;
 }
 AddressData is also my class name  how its work with my result set

Comment: Can you describe your scenario a bit better (maybe in a new question)? If I understand right what you ask now, you are talkjing about the code that calls the `read` method, right? I guess is better to create a new question about this part of the problem.

Comment: Note in too that in Java is common _not_ to use capital letters for variables. so the class is `AddressData` and the variable of this type `addressData`.

Comment: wait i define a new question

Comment: hey bro i want store my data in the AddressData class that have setter/getter method how it will done?

Answer (score 0):

I may not understand your question, but if you're looking to store your results in `AddressData`, and then add that to an `ArrayList`, you could do it like this:

```
//...
resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
ArrayList addresses = new ArrayList<AddressData>();
AddressData aData;
while (resultSet.next()) {
    aData = new AddressData();

    // Store the results in aData
    aData.setAddressId(resultSet.getString("addressId");
    aData.setAddressLine1(resultSet.getString("addressLine1"));
    aData.setAddressLine2(resultSet.getString("addressLine2");
    aData.setCity(resultSet.getString("city");
    aData.setState(resultSet.getString("state"));
    aData.setCountry(resultSet.getString("country"));
    aData.setPinCode(resultSet.getString("pinCode"));

    // Add the data to our addresses list
    addresses.add(aData);
}
//...
```

I am assuming that all fields are strings. If say `pinCode` was not a string, but an int, you would have to use `resultSet.getInt("pinCode")` as your argument to your setter function.